# Creating Context Menu using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

How can i create a context menu on Arcgis Desktop.And after creating it,how can i use it while a base command is open and active.I use C# but i can understand visual basic.

Answer (score 2):

To instantiate it pass mapcontrol.Object as the parameter to the constructor.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.SystemUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls;

namespace MapLibrary.ContextMenus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Context menu class for Engine applications.
    ///</summary>
    [Guid("d71c6409-7f8b-4f23-95ed-12ba0d461920")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("MapLibrary.ContextMenus.BasicContextMenu1")]
    public class BasicContextMenu1
    {
        private IToolbarMenu2 m_toolbarMenu = null;
        private bool m_beginGroupFlag = false;

        public BasicContextMenu1(object hook)
        {
            this.SetHook(hook); 
        }

        public void SetHook(object hook)
        {
            m_toolbarMenu = new ToolbarMenuClass();
            m_toolbarMenu.SetHook(hook);
            AddItem("esriControls.ControlsMapZoomInTool", -1);
            AddItem("esriControls.ControlsMapZoomOutTool", -1);
            AddItem("esriControls.ControlsMapFullExtentCommand", -1);
            AddItem("esriControls.ControlsMapPanTool", -1);
            AddItem("esriControls.ControlsMapIdentifyTool", -1);
        }

        public void PopupMenu(int X, int Y, int hWndParent)
        {
            if (m_toolbarMenu != null) m_toolbarMenu.PopupMenu(X, Y, hWndParent);
        }

        public IToolbarMenu2 ContextMenu
        {
            get
            {
                return m_toolbarMenu;
            }
        }

        private void BeginGroup()
        {
            m_beginGroupFlag = true;
        }

        private void AddItem(UID itemUID)
        {
            m_toolbarMenu.AddItem(itemUID.Value, itemUID.SubType, -1, m_beginGroupFlag, esriCommandStyles.esriCommandStyleIconAndText);
            m_beginGroupFlag = false; //Reset group flag
        }

        private void AddItem(string itemID, int subtype)
        {
            UID itemUID = new UIDClass();
            try
            {
                itemUID.Value = itemID;
            }
            catch
            {
                itemUID.Value = Guid.Empty.ToString("B");
            }

            if (subtype > 0)
                itemUID.SubType = subtype;
            AddItem(itemUID);

        }

        private void AddItem(Guid itemGuid, int subtype)
        {
            AddItem(itemGuid.ToString("B"), subtype);
        }

         private void AddItem(Type itemType, int subtype)
        {
            if (itemType != null) AddItem(itemType.GUID, subtype);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is at least a sample in your installation directory. I dont remember the name of the sample but you should have no difficulty in finding it